# How can I handle the 'max_user_connections' in mysql and php?

Tags: php, mysql, database

The error message occur when I have multiple request in the server. and my server hosting told me that my max user connection is only 15. how can i manage this request and avoid this error.?

Answer (score 3):

In my.cnf put:

```
max_connections=100
```

or if you can't change this file, you'll have to limit the number of connections in your php software (if you are using a pool or similar) to avoid reach this limit.

Comment: i'm not familiar with mysql pooling...can you give some links or info about this "pooling"?

Comment: it depends on the php framewor you are sing (or not). If you are not using any framework php does not offer you pooling and you are the responsible to create the logic behind reuse of connections to create your own pooling. Basically you should use mysql_ponnect instead of mysql_connect and be aware of the number of opened connections and time-out of already opened connections.

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon your environment the answer can vary greatly. The main point point is you need to better manage your connections; remember to close them when you are done, re-use them when you can. Without knowing your stack I can't give you better advice. You may wish to check if you are opening up a persistent connection and not closing it.

Comment: how can i check if there's open persistent connection??

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php
The difference is really if you are using mysql_connect or mysql_pconnect.

Comment: I would try your code against both mysql_connect and mysql_pconnect. I think pconnect will try and reuse connections and not establish a new one per server request.

Comment: You could also get creative with tcpdump on the connections outbound from the php box you are using. TCP dumps will indicate when a connection is being reused or forces a close.

Answer (score 1):

1. Switch to a different hosting provider/package
2. Improve the performance of your queries by refactoring the queries and changing indexing
3. Don't open db connections in your code until you need to run a query
4. explicitly close db connections immediately after they are no longer required
5. If you are running the same queries repeatedly, cache the data outside the DBMS (much less efficient / requires much more code than using DB caching)

Answer (score 0):

For those still looking for the latest information on this topic mysql_pconnect: This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5. 0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. One can try prepending "p:" to the host name in connecting to mysqli in order make use of persistent behavior.

Alternatives to mysql_pconnect include:

1) mysqli_connect() with p: host prefix
Example:

```
mysqli_connect('p:192.168.x.y', 'USER', 'PWD', 'DB', 3306);
```

2) PDO::__construct() with PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT as a driver option**

Example:

```
   try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_host;dbname=$database",  $mysql_user, $mysql_password, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT=>true));
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die ("<b>Cannot connect to database, check user credentials.</b>");
   }
```